# Как при клике по кнопке прятать один элемент и показывать другой и наоборот?

Tags: jquery

Нужно, чтобы при каждом клике по кнопке ее содержимое (иконки) менялось.

На данный момент удалось при клике сменить иконку, но при повторном клике иконка уже не меняется. Как это исправить?

[Ссылка](https://worldwarmworm.github.io/doorhan/) на проект

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```js
$('.toggle-button_1').click(function() {
  $('.item-1__content').toggle(300);

  if ($('.toggle-button .show-icon')) {
    $('.toggle-button .show-icon').hide();
    $('.toggle-button .hide-icon').show();
  } else {
    $('.toggle-button .hide-icon').hide();
    $('.toggle-button .show-icon').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.show-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: "icomoon";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transition: .3s;
}

.hide-icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: "icomoon";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-button toggle-button_1">
  <div class="show-icon">&#xf103;</div>
  <div class="hide-icon">&#xf102;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вместо условий и `.hide(), .show()` можно использовать `$(...).toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Условие в

```
if ($('.toggle-button .show-icon')) {
```

всегда возвращает `true`.

---

```
$('.toggle-button_1').click(function () {
    $('.item-1__content').toggle(300);

    if ($('.toggle-button .show-icon').is(":visible")) { // !!!
        $('.toggle-button .show-icon').hide();
        $('.toggle-button .hide-icon').show();
    } else {
        $('.toggle-button .hide-icon').hide();
        $('.toggle-button .show-icon').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Блин! Я же учил!
Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ВалерийДавыдкин Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.